# Excel created with EPPlus having no data but large size

Tags: c#, .net, export-to-excel, epplus

I am using EPPlus open source tool for creating / editing excel files on server.
When I insert data to excel created by EPPlus by opening it using C# .net code some time size of files gets increase upto 8-10Mb.
If I copy all content in MS Excel from that file and save it then it is of only 20 kb.

What should be the actual cause behind increasing excel file size created by EPPlus

Comment: How much data are you inserting? When you open the sheet with Excel do you see the expected data?  Is it a xls or xlsx file?

Comment: What do you do when inserting data? code?

Comment: No not fix value of insertion some time single record some time 20-30 records

Comment: I upload excel & copy-paste content from cell to cell

Comment: @edTarik Data is very much important...

Comment: And when i open that excel I got expected data in sheet & it is .xlsx file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was due to unreadable content generated in excel it self. When I used new release of EPPlus (4.1.0) I have not get any problem like this.